# UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext , alloc version?

Tags: ios, image

UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext returns autoreleased UIImage.

Wonder if there is a way to get "alloc"-ed image from context?

I want something equivalent to following code, maybe the code is best I can do?

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];     
UIImage* image = get image by UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContenxt
[image retain];
[pool release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call `-retain` on the result.

```
UIImage *image = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain];
```

Comment: i want to release the image when I want. even if i retain as you suggested, i can't release it when i want to release, because it's also in autorelease pool

Comment: Why are you worrying about it being in an autorelease pool? Unless you're making hundreds of these things in a single pass through the run loop, it shouldn't matter. And if it does matter, then you can just create your own autorelease pool like you demonstrated.